# How to derive (get derivative) a function inside a function using Autograd?

Tags: python, derivative, autograd, automatic-differentiation

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def f(x, y):
    def g(w):
        def h(z):
            return z * (w ** 2) * (x + y)
        return h
    return g
```

I want to calculate the partial derivatives of **f** w.r.t (x, y, w, z) at point say (x0, y0, w0, z0) using **autograd**.
The code is of course in python.
Thanks.

Comment: `f` doesn't have the partial derivatives you're asking for. It's a function of two arguments that returns another function, not a function of four arguments that returns a number.

Comment: If you want to find the partial derivatives of the related function `def f2(x, y, w, z): return f(x, y)(w)(z)`, you should be able to handle f2 just like any other function.